# Jquery Ui is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Hi i'm trying an simple jquery ui example but it is not working and i dont understand why. can anybody help me?  thx

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css">

<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                $('#datepicker').datepicker({
                    inline: true
                });
            });
        </script>
  </head>
  <body>
              <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="datepicker">



  </body>
</html>
```

I really dont understand why its not working. all the includes are in the same folder can be found by clicking the link in my sourcecode view of mozilla firefox browser 15.0

Comment: Did you try to change the order in which the files are loaded (so `jquery` would start before `jquery-ui`)?

Comment: Actually my first comment was wrong, rain's is right; an input would work in that it won't use an icon, but will work if you click on it

Comment: You should include what the expected and actual behavior is in your question (What is "wrong" and what would you like it to be.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jQuery-ui.js` should be imported after `jQuery.js`?

Since you're using firefox I recommend [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) console. It will show you any errors your javascript throws.

Under normal conditions when the browser encounters a script tag it will begin downloading it and puting it in a queue for execution. So the code of jQuery-ui will be executed before the code in jQuery and since the ui frameworks references jQuery it will throw an exeption.

There are multiple solutions to enable out of order execution but **the simplest** is to make sure all the dependency files are loaded before the ones that need them.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've got jQuery UI before jQuery.

Comment: thank u very much for your help. can u tell me why this is neccessary? i tought the order of the includes doesnt matter..